# Interstitial video ad close shows previous screen for 1 - 2 seconds before navigating to the second screen

Tags: android, android-intent, admob

Here is my Activity Code Click Listenter

```
binding.startbtn.setOnClickListener({
        if(AdunitIDs.mInterstitialAd!=null){
            Admob(object : OnDismiss {
                override fun onDismiss() {
                    if(isFirstTimeScan) {
                        moveToRecoverActivity()
                    } else {
                        var intent = Intent(Intent(this@ScanData_Activity,Scan_Process_Activity::class.java))
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }).showInt(this@ScanData_Activity, true)
        }else{
            if(isFirstTimeScan) {
                moveToRecoverActivity()
            } else {
                var intent = Intent(Intent(this@ScanData_Activity,Scan_Process_Activity::class.java))
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    }
})
```

Admob Show Interestial Function

```
fun showInt(activity: Activity, isReload: Boolean) {
        AdunitIDs.mInterstitialAd!!.setFullScreenContentCallback(object : FullScreenContentCallback() {

           
                 override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                Log.i("##i" ,"Ad Will Dismiss Full Screen Content Called")
                if (isReload) {
                    AdunitIDs.mInterstitialAd = null
                 
                    loadInt(activity,null)
         
                }
                onDismiss.onDismiss()
            }


            override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError)
                Log.i("##i"," Ad Failed To Show Full Screen Content") 
                AdunitIDs.mInterstitialAd=null
                loadInt(activity,null,null)
                onDismiss.onDismiss()
            }
        })
        AdunitIDs.mInterstitialAd!!.show(activity)

    }
    }
```

The issue occurs only Video Ad

I want to Fix problem when There is Video Interestial Ad It didn't go back to last Screen and when Ad is Close